# Static Positioned Div with minus Margin display Partially in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've designed this page to show a picture gallery with a description for each picture. I use a div with static position and minus left and top margins, so the description is shown on top of the bottom part of the image.

The problem is that if I open the page for the first time with Firefox, the Div displays only partially (only on top of the image part is shown). Only when I click any other album does the div displays correctly.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kGDu.jpg) is the bad display image

The description div should have been displayed until the bottom of the container div. Try clicking another thumbnail image at the test site page.

[This](http://binusmaya.110mb.com/ant/) is the test site, to open the page, click the gallery menu, the one on the left bottom with a dog picture.

Has anyone encounter the same problem? Hope someone could help me. Any advice will be welcomed gladly.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not trying to dampen your spirits, but you should Google for the term "mystery meat navigation".

Comment: Is there any chance you could make a second version of this, which does not include any AJAX? It's making it difficult for me to test this.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I agree with you for the MMN, but I don't have the authorization to change the design. I afraid it could take some time before I could make the non-AJAX version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've managed to solve the problem. It seems that the div is shown partially to the end of the Image tag just before the div. so then, I wrap the image in another div setting the div's height the same height of the image. I've tried it, and it looks find in FF now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I found the answer. I just put '!important' on the height attribute. And then Firefox displays the div fully!

Thank you, I should've thought that.

Comment: +1 for coming back to post an answer. However, the live site you linked to in your question still has the same problem for me. Maybe you've simply not put the fix live yet?

Comment: ah, my bad... this has not fixed the problem. The problem occur for the very first time I open the page. Seems that it won't occur the second time I open it even if I closed the tab, except if I closed Firefox and reopen the page again

Comment: To ensure the bug happens, refresh with CTRL+F5. If you make a version without AJAX, and I'll still take another look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Use "position: relative" with negative "top" and "left" values.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I've Tried that, but the problem is that the description div is not even displayed in IE 7. Therefore I changed to 'static' position.